MariaDB *M!999999 error on 11.5.2 preventing import of sql dump
I recently upgraded to MariaDB 11.5.2. The database was also updated via the update command and I ensured the version I was running.
I exported using the MariaDB-dump (i also ensured this was the same version). Problem is when I import I get this error:

/*M!999999- enable the sandbox mode */
-- MariaDB dump 10.19-11.5.2-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
-- Host: localhost    Database: DB

-- Server version       11.5.2-MariaDB-ubu2204
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT /;
/!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS /;
/!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION /;
/!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 /; /!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE
/; /!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' /; /!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 /; /!40014 SET
@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 /;
/!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE,
SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */; /*M!100616 SET
@OLD_NOTE_VERBOSITY=@@NOTE_VERBOSITY, NOTE_VERBOSITY=0 /; /!40103
SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE /; /!40014 SET
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS /; /!40014 SET
UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS /; /!40101 SET
CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT /; /!40101 SET
CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS /; /!40101 SET
COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */; /*M!100616 SET
NOTE_VERBOSITY=@OLD_NOTE_VERBOSITY */;

Now I posted a question here thinking it was still outputting the old version and that this was a compatibility issue. I have dealt with the 999999 error before and solved it using the sed and tail+2 commands.
But this is different. Those solutions do not work and looking at the header the sandbox is different. "M!999999". So M is added before the !.
@danblack confirmed this stating:

Yes, M was inserted last release to make this only parsed by MariaDB
clients. This way mysql clients can interact (but technically are
vulnerable)

That's fine and dandy. But how the heck am I suppossed to import the backup now? It gets the same sandbox issue whether I try to upload it in a fresh install or another database on the same machine.
My guess is that the sed/tail +2 command needs to changed to accomodate the extra M character from the solution listed on the website, but I am not having luck appending the command. Other than that, is there a way to just turn the sandbox off while importing?
For reference the old solution (that did not have the extra M character) was this:
run sed -i ‘1{/999999.*sandbox/d}’ dump.sql on the dump file before importing.
or
mariadb-dump|tail +2 at backup
tail +2|mariadb at import
I have tried that and sed -i ‘1{/M!999999.*sandbox/d} to no avail.

Found out what I was doing wrong.
I was using mariadb-dump to import instead of just mariadb. Mariadb-dump is for exports only.
